# Arch linux fsck checks failing

Tags: linux

Here's a photo of what's going on https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Hrj.jpg

Alright 100000 IQ linux wizards, what do I do here? xP
All my files and everything is still there when I booted from a USB and mounted the hard drive, so I don't know what's broken here and how to fix it.

I get those same errors when I run fsck on dev mapper crypt root. It says something about errors and "Do you want to force rewrite" and the same errors continue and it does this over and over in a never ending loop.

How can I perform SMART self assessment checks or any disk checks on CLI? Is this fixable or do I have to reinstall everything or is the hard drive toast?

Comment: OK for some reason the link you provided for a screenshot isn't showing an image for me. So I'm kind of running blind here. Does `fsck` offer to *correct* (write) toi the disk in an effort to *fix* the error(s) it discovers? Are you booting to so-called "single user" before attempting to execute `fsck`? So that it can actually *write* to the disk? As to SMART. I don't know what version of Linux you're using. But you should start it as a service; see https://manpage.me/?q=smartd&manpath=CentOS+7.1 for some clues. Also, what does your BIOS report regarding SMART for your drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing indicates a hardware failure.

Depending on the value of the data, stop using the computer and send the drive to a recovery expert.

If the data is not that valuable, but still highly desireable, get another equal or larger size disk and copy the undamaged bits off, using a partition copy. I would recommend (GNU) ddrescue as it will try very hard to pull your data off. I would run it forward, then when it slows/stops try in reverse, then let it run as long as you can.

You should then ideally make a copy of the copy, and try to run `chkdsk` on that (if the `chkdsk` corrupts, you can always reclone the data and try different strategies). Most of the times though, `chkdsk` should get most of your data back.